# Unable to add assembly to the GAC

Tags: c#, gac

**gacutil** confirms that I've added my own assembly to the **GAC**. But when I go to look, it's not there. I know that for version 4 and above,  they are located in `GAC_MSIL`. But it's not there either despite the following message in the developer command prompt:

> C:\Users\Matheus\source>gacutil /l CarLibrary Microsoft (R) .NET
>   Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.0 Copyright (c)
>   Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
>   CarLibrary, Version=1.0.6685.33745, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=a9431d52640b43f3, processorArchitecture=MSIL
>   CarLibrary, Version=1.0.6685.35757, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=a27f772b6d6ad3a3, processorArchitecture=MSIL
>
> Number of items = 2

Comment: "Version=1.0.6685.33745".  That is where that problem starts.  You are forcing msbuild to auto-generate the version number, done with [AssemblyVersion(1.0.*)] in the AssemblyInfo.cs source file.  Very, **very** bad idea, you get a new version every time you build the assembly.  Complete poison to the GAC, you already got 2 versions of it, you'll keep adding more to fix this problem.  Absolutely crucial to pick an explicit version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm still learning the languages (C# and english). I did what you said and reconfigured AssemblyInfo after uninstalling the assembly and then I reinstalled it. However, prompt shows the same message, that I successfully installed, but it's not there. I tried to do all again, but it is still the same.

Comment: If gacutil says it is in the GAC you can be pretty sure it is. So what is the real problem you are having? And you are sure you can't find them in C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL nor C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I didn't look that path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL. It is there! I thought "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL"  was the only path I could try to search.